# Mac: NSWindowController, view does not open after it's closed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode5

This is probably something simple that I am missing but this is what is happening:

I am making a Menu item app (application is agent = YES)

So I have a MainViewAppDelegate that kind of runs the entire thing. It gets a detection when a button on the menu item gets clicked.

Then I have an upload NSWindowController:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface UploadView : NSWindowController
- (IBAction)upload:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m:

```
-(id)init {
    if (! (self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"UploadView"])) {
        // Initialization code here.
        return nil;
    }

    return self;
}
```

In MainViewAppDelegate, when that button is pressed I do:

```
if (!uploadView) {
    uploadView = [[UploadView alloc] init];
}
[uploadView showWindow:self];
```

Now, this works as long as I don't click out of xcode. Once I do that (say I make chrome the active tab) then it does not work anymore even if I go back to xcode.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My gut tells me it has to do with the `retain` properties within your nib file for `UploadView`.

Comment: Check your outlets.  When NIBs are first loaded with no connections you are given a phantom connection to a window that promptly disappears after it has been closed the first time (because, you know, that seemed reasonable to somebody 20-ish years ago).

Comment: And the there is the "Release on close" checkbox for NSWindow that used to be the (not very helpful) default.

Comment: It's really confusing me. It does not seem like it has anything to do with it being closed. If I close it and not leave xcode it opens up again. It's just if I make some other window the active one it stops working. Here is my entire code base if that helps: https://github.com/Jonovono/cutter It's mainly the MainViewAppDelegate and UploadView

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any issue in the UploadView code. But can you try connecting the UploadView Panel in xib to File's Owner window outlet and try. I created a similar demo now and tried and i dont see any issue.

Comment: Ya, I have the Panel in the UploadView connected to the Files Owner in the UploadView xib, still not working.

Comment: I dont see binding of window to the panel in the code you provided.

Comment: Do you mean like ctrl-click drag from "Panel-Window" to "Files Owner" above and create a new referencing object where  "window" pops up?

Comment: AHA! I got it. Thanks for you help. What I had to do was add: [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]; to the function that opens the view and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to add was:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

before trying to open the window.